# C - printf inside "if" statement doesn't show

Tags: c

I'm trying to make this `printf` inside the `if` statement show, but it doesn't. Here is the code, I've highlighted the `printf` section.

```
char conv;
float cel;

printf("Enter what you'd like converted: \n\t1.Celcius to Fahrenheit\n\t2.Inch to CM\n\t3.CM to Inch\n");
scanf_s("%c", &conv);

// This one
if (conv == '1')
    printf("Please enter amount of Celcius: \n");
scanf_s("%f", &cel);

float fahr;
fahr = 33.8 * cel;

printf("Conversion of %f Celsius is %f Fahrenheit", cel, fahr);

getch();
return 0;
```

What is the reason for this?

Comment: When I tried to use the normal "scanf" is said that it was unsafe to use and that I rather should use "scanf_s". I'm using Visual Studio 13.

Comment: `scanf_s("%c", &conv);` --> `scanf_s("%c", &conv, 1);`

Comment: No compiler error for faulty arguments?

Comment: @Jongware: It's not considered *faulty arguments* with a function that takes a variable number of arguments (there is nothing faulty about it as far as the compiler's concerned, i.e., until actual runtime).

Comment: @barak: gcc *does* notice such things. Saved my bacon a couple of times, too.

Comment: @Kreator: `scanf` can be dangerous if used carelessly. You can shut the compiler warning by setting `/D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` globally or `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` before `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: `scanf` can be dangerous if used.

Comment: @Almo: I'd wager we're not talking converting body temperatures for a remote open heart surgery piece of equipment !

Comment: note that `°C = (°F - 32)/1.8` and `°F = °C*1.8 + 32`, not like your formula

Answer (score 0):

```
In looking at the line: scanf_s("%c", &conv);  
I see the function scanf_s(), 
which in not in any C library that I'm familiar with.

However, the function scanf(), which is in the C libraries, 
has the following prototype and usage:

int scanf(const char *format, ...)

where the return value is the number of items in the variable parameter list '...'
that were actually filled from the input.

I.E. your code should, after the call to scanf_s() check the return code
those value should be 1 in your example.

Then you have this code:

if (conv == '1')
    printf("Please enter amount of Celcius: \n");
scanf_s("%f", &cel);

supposedly with the idea that all those following lines would be 
enclosed in the 'if' block.
however, only the first line following the 'if' is actually part of the
'if' block.
To correct this problem, write the code using braces to delineate
the 'if' block, like this:

if (conv == '1')
{
    printf("Please enter amount of Celcius: \n");
    scanf_s("%f", &cel);

    float fahr;
    fahr = 33.8 * cel; // BTW: this is not the correct conversion formula

    printf("Conversion of %f Celsius is %f Fahrenheit", cel, fahr);
}
```